# Android navigation Drawer showing 2 fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

So I’m working on an android app that needs to show 2 fragments side by side and still have the option to use a navigation drawer like this
[Image link can't post images :(](http://postimg.org/image/r1d9xvyv7/)

My problem is that when I’m trying to add any fragments into the xml file I’m getting the following error

```
  06-17 12:18:14.384    2377-2377/com.example.evemanufacturing3.app E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-17 12:18:14.452    2377-2377/com.example.evemanufacturing3.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-17 12:18:14.456    2377-2377/com.example.evemanufacturing3.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6236288)
06-17 12:18:14.460    2377-2377/com.example.evemanufacturing3.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.evemanufacturing3.app/com.example.evemanufacturing3.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.example.evemanufacturing3.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File null/std contains a path separator
            at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1680)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.validateFilePath(ContextImpl.java:1664)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:807)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at database.databaseAdapterEveStaticDataDump.getT1ModulesNames(databaseAdapterEveStaticDataDump.java:84)
            at com.example.evemanufacturing3.app.ManufacturingFragment.onCreateView(ManufacturingFragment.java:91)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:807)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4664)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.example.evemanufacturing3.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my drawfragment.xml file lookes like this

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top">


            <fragment
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.example.evemanufacturing3.app.ManufacturingFragment"
                android:id="@+id/fe1"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_manufacturing"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment2" />
            <fragment
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.example.evemanufacturing3.app.manufacturingOptionsFragment"
                android:id="@+id/fe2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_options"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.evemanufacturing3.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and my MainActivity lookes like this

move to like becouse off size restriction

[past bin link code to version 1 off MainActity moved](http://pastebin.com/z1JDvXvg)

i been trying to change to the activity to extend fragmentActivity instead off activity witch didt work :(
i also been trying to move the 2 fragments in to a different xml file and setting the content to the new xml didn’t work :( maybe me making some stupid error I’m really bad at android layout :(

My app works fine if i only add fragments from MainActivity but then dos not show the second fragment... the second I’m adding the fragments to the xml code my app crashes on start

EDIT

still no progress :( 
i been traying to change the layout a bit and even setting a totaly new layout file and still traying to keep the navigation drawer but still getting the same creash errors :(

any idears??

EDIT 2
force me to remove first version off MainActivity becouse off size restrictions

so i been googling some more after a replay.
i changed all imports to be

> android.support.v4.app.

witch didt make any difference so i trayed running a debugger to see what linje the app failed at the line was

> setContentView(R.layout.drawfragment);

so that made me think that i might cut change the setcontent to anothere xml contaning a relativ layout and 2 fragments gives the same error so i trayed removing the 2 fragments witch gave me an error men traying to create the navigation drawer.

any one have a solution to this problem ?? ore due i need some diffrent way off creating the navigation drawer?

new MainActivity lookes like this alot off the off topic have changed but not much diffrence in the topic related code

```
package com.example.evemanufacturing3.app;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import com.example.evemanufacturing3.app.Dialogs.PickCharDialog;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import database.DatabaseAdapterApp;
import database.copyEveStaticDataDump;
import eveAPI.Download;
import eveCental.EveCentalDownload;
import holders.ApiSet;
import holders.Chars;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, EveCentalDownload.communicator,PickCharDialog.Communicator,Download.communicator,copyEveStaticDataDump.communicator {


    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // fragment
    FragmentManager manager;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;

    // eve xml
    public static ArrayList<Chars> myChars;
    static String AccountBalanceFileName = "test.xml";
    public static String accountFileName ="AccountFileName.xml";
    public static String MainDir;
    public static ArrayList<String> keyid = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> VerificationCode = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> charsOnAccount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//    public static ArrayList<ApiSet> apiSets = new ArrayList<ApiSet>();
    public Chars activeChar;
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public static ProgressDialog mProgressdialog;
    //manufacturing fragment

    Fragment charFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.drawfragment);
        MainDir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/EveManufactoring";


        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

//        MainDir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/EveManufactoring";
        //   MainDir = "/sdcard/EveManufactoring/";
        myChars = new ArrayList<Chars>();



//        DatabaseAdapterApp db = new DatabaseAdapterApp(this,MainDir);
//        ApiSet api = new ApiSet();
//        api.setKeyID("2823552");
//        api.setVcode("1pD3U6DB0KBha3v0MtUHGkiYZVVVqJNqorESaoFgsjVZ2Rd2tCwnd5b0tTM1lkxE");
//        db.addApiSet(api);



        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            SharedPreferences();




    }

    private void SharedPreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        if (settings.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)) {
            //the app is being launched for first time, do something
            Log.d("Comments", "First time");

            // first time task
            DatabaseAdapterApp db = new DatabaseAdapterApp(this,MainDir);
//            db.recreateEveApiSets();
            mProgressdialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "downliading api data", "loading");
            mProgressdialog.setCancelable(false);

            mProgressdialog.show();

            copyEveStaticDataDump d = new copyEveStaticDataDump(this,MainDir);
            d.setCommunicator(this);
            d.execute();


            // record the fact that the app has been started at least once
            settings.edit().putBoolean("my_first_time", false).commit();
        }else {
            DatabaseAdapterApp db = new DatabaseAdapterApp(this,null);
            File f = new File(MainDir +"/" + db.getDatabaseName() );
            if (!f.exists()) {
//                new CreateDBAndFill(this,keyid,VerificationCode).execute("");

                int r =0;
                mProgressdialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "downliading api data", "loading");
                mProgressdialog.setCancelable(false);

                mProgressdialog.show();
                ApiSet a = new ApiSet("2823552","1pD3U6DB0KBha3v0MtUHGkiYZVVVqJNqorESaoFgsjVZ2Rd2tCwnd5b0tTM1lkxE");
                Download d = new Download(this,a);
                d.setCommunicator(this);
                d.execute("");

            }else{
//                SqlDbHelper db = new SqlDbHelper(myContext);
//                db.open();
//                myChars =db.getTempData();
//                db.close();
//                p.dismiss();
                PickCharDialog p = new PickCharDialog();
                p.setCommunicator(this);
                p.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),null);
//              new Download(this, keyid, VerificationCode).execute("");
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
//                CharFragment f = new CharFragment();
//                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
//                transaction.add(R.id.container,f,"Char");
//                transaction.commit();
//                Download d = new Download(this,apiSets);
//                d.setCommunicator(this);
//                d.execute("");
//                new Download( this, keyid, VerificationCode).execute("");
//                mProgressdialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "downliading api data", "loading");
//                mProgressdialog.setCancelable(false);
//
//                mProgressdialog.show();


                break;
            case 2:

                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                charFragment = manager.findFragmentByTag("Char");
                FragmentTransaction transaction1 = manager.beginTransaction();
                ManufacturingFragment m = new ManufacturingFragment();



                    transaction1.add(R.id.fe1, m, "Manufactoring");
//                    transaction1.add(R.id.fe2,new manufacturingOptionsFragment(),"manufacturingOptions");
                    transaction1.commit();


                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }

    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public void updateApiData(ArrayList<Chars> c) {
        mProgressdialog.dismiss();
        this.myChars = c;
        PickCharDialog p = new PickCharDialog();
        p.PickCharDialog(c);
        p.setCommunicator(this);
        p.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),null);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateActiveChar(Chars c) {
        this.activeChar = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateManufacturingListView() {

    }


    @Override
    public void copyEveStaticDataDumpComplete() {
        mProgressdialog.dismiss();
        SharedPreferences();

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `Fragments` available in `com.example.evemanufacturing3.app` packages?

Comment: well java app files are places in com.example.evemanufacturing3.app
and all xml files are pleas in res/layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the error :P thanks alot to vojtaaa9 for the effort found the error to be something that no one cut figur out bay what i postet in here :(

found that for some reason when the views was inflated they called a sqllite db im using in the fragment but the db class was depening on the mainclass to be fully initilized before working so it was cursing the creash when it was inflating the view :(

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File null/std contains a path separator
            at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1680)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.validateFilePath(ContextImpl.java:1664)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:807)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at database.databaseAdapterEveStaticDataDump.getT1ModulesNames(databaseAdapterEveStaticDataDump.java:84)
            at com.example.evemanufacturing3.app.ManufacturingFragment.onCreateView(ManufacturingFragment.java:91)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:807)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4664)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.example.evemanufacturing3.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

fixed the file null/sted to get it's own patch for the sdcard and now it works :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using only support library imports. Because navigation drawer is only in support library, you cant call import android.app.Fragment;

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Make also other imports from [support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html). In Eclipse, delete them, then press Crtl+Shift+o and then choose supportlibrary imports.

I hope this helps :)

**EDIT1:**

Try to remove

```
 tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
```

And one performance suggestion, you dont have to use `<FrameLayout>` , just use `<RelativeLayout>`.

**EDIT2:**
For the first fragment set

```
android:id="@+id/fe1"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fe2"
```

for the second

```
android:id="@id/fe2"
```

For the [drawer view](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout) you have to specify horizontal gravity

> •The drawer view must specify its horizontal gravity with the android:layout_gravity attribute. To support right-to-left (RTL) languages, specify the value with "start" instead of "left" (so the drawer appears on the right when the layout is RTL).

which means in your third fragment:

```
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   ...
/>
```

I apologize for my English, if something isnt clear, just tell me ;-)

Comment: nop didnt work :( pleas read edit 2 in topic i made some changes and trayed some new stuff still no idear why the error